# Is it possible to simulate a postgres query without actually running it?

Tags: postgresql

I'm developing a pipeline that communicates a lot to my postgres database.

I'm trying to figure out how I can create a "dry run" mode for my pipeline that essentially uses the fewest resources possible just to see if the pipeline *can* and *would* run properly.

I understand that I could just *not* commit my changes to my database at the end of my script, but it takes about an hour for my pipeline to run all the way through. So it'd be cool if I could just simulate a lot of my postgres queries without actually taking the time to run all of them.

I'll give you an extremely simple example so you can see what I mean...

Let's say the only things in my pipeline are refreshing a bunch of materialized views. But they take a long time to refresh, and there's a lot of them. So I'd like to simply ask the postgres db... "hey, if I ran these refreshes right now, would it go through correctly?"

I feel like this is kinda what happens during the "query planning" phase, but this is just an intuition.

I also acknowledge that the only way to know for absolute sure is to actually run it, but let's just say for now that I know and accept the risks that come along with that.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*would it go through correctly*"? You can only be sure by actually running it. What level of simulation are you aiming for? Connecting to "postgres-like" server without a database; parsing the SQL queries you send; planning the SQL queries; running the SQL queries; returning their results of the run; committing the results to a disk? There's so many points where you could "stop simulating".

Comment: You could set a smallish statement_timeout.  If you get the timeout error rather than some other error, then the REFRESH at least parsed and began to execute.  That is no guarantee it would have executed successfully, of course, but is better than nothing.   It requires your pipeline to be flexible enough to ignore errors and restart transactions when in this mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `SELECT` statements, you could prepend `EXPLAIN` to the statement. That won't return the proper result set, but when it succeeds, the statement should run (unless there is a runtime error).
However, that does not work with `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW`...

I guess the best option you have is to use a database that has all the tables, views, functions etc., but is empty. Most statements will complete very quickly on an empty database.

Comment: Ooo that's a really interesting idea, and some great information. Thanks for sharing!